# looping files and extracting segments in Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I am trying to create a loop and extrat some segments of files located in a folder. I could easily do it in R but in Python I am having trouble. I have already tried with os and with glob.

The code in R looks like this:

```
## loop over all files
for (i in 1:length(file)) {

    ## extract file name
    file.name <- strsplit(file[i],"\\.")[[1]][1]

    ## extract file header
    file.head <- readLines(file[i], n = length(grep("#", readLines(file[i]))))
....
```

and the code in Python that I made looks like this (path is the directoy):

```
for file in os.listdir(path):

    ## extract file name
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)

    ## extract file header
    tempfile = os.open(file, os.O_RDWR)
```

Altough I am new in Python, I didnt believe such simple thing would be so time consuming. I appreciate the help, as I have already scoutted the web for an answer.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: the error is on the tempfile:
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-638830dc1bc8> in <module>()
----> 1 tempfile = os.open(file, os.O_RDWR)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir) to get paths, rather than filenames.

Then, use `file.readlines()`:

```
for file in os.scandir(path):
    tempfile = os.open(file).readlines()
```

I am unfamiliar with R syntax, but it appears that you want to get all of the lines that begin with `#`. To do that, just use a list comprehension:

```
for file in os.scandir(path):
    tempfile = [l for l in os.open(file).readlines() if l[0] == '#']
```

In fact, you can iterate over the file directly which will iterate over the lines:

```
for file in os.scandir(path):
    tempfile = [l for l in os.open(file) if l[0] == '#']
```